# Yacc/Bison semantic value changes mid way through rule

Tags: bison, yacc

```
iteration_stmt : WHILE              {$$ = LabelSeed; LabelSeed++;
                                     fprintf(fp, "While%i:\n", $$);
                                    }
                 '(' expression ')' {fprintf(fp, "cmp %s, 1\n", regToString($<n>3));
                                     fprintf(fp, "jne EndWhile%i\n", $$);
                                     NextReg--;
                                    }
                 statement          {fprintf(fp, "jmp While%i\n", $$);
                                     fprintf(fp, "EndWhile%i:\n", $$);
                                    }
                ;
```

I'm trying to use **iteration_stmt**'s semantic value to keep track of the **LabelSeed** value, however it's value doesn't stay the same through out the other 2 actions. For example, in one case my output is:

```
While0:
...
jne EndWhile1
...
jmp While0
EndWhile0:
```

in another its:

```
While2:
...
jne EndWhile2
...
jmp While0
EndWhile0:
```

The integer should stay constant. I cant think of any reason the semantic value would change. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semantic value of **iteration_stmt** will not be set until the *entire* rule is reduced, at which point $$ can be used to refer to it in the action code.  Your use of $$ in the action code segments actually refers to implicit partially completed parts of the rule; only in the action for the ending **statement** non-terminal will $$ refer to **iteration_stmt**.

This is because internally yacc/bison implements [rules with mid-rule actions](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_6.html#SEC48) as a cascade of rules of regular form, with actions at the end only.

So, try this:

```
iteration_stmt : WHILE              {$$ = LabelSeed; LabelSeed++;
                                     fprintf(fp, "While%i:\n", $$);
                                    }
                 '(' expression ')' {fprintf(fp, "cmp %s, 1\n", regToString($<n>3));
                                     fprintf(fp, "jne EndWhile%i\n", $1);
                                     NextReg--;
                                    }
                 statement          {fprintf(fp, "jmp While%i\n", $1);
                                     fprintf(fp, "EndWhile%i:\n", $1);
                                    }
                ;
```

Where the first $$ loads a semantic value for the **WHILE** token, which the other actions can reference.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed another little bug in my program since I was messing up the value stack. Just to let others know, what I did was create a sub-rule that performed the first action, and used that rule to hold LabelSeed. Basically the same as your idea, except I don't have to set the value in lex.

`whilesubroutine : WHILE    {$$ = LabelSeed++; 
                             fprintf(fp, "While%i:\n", $$);
                            };`

Comment: Breaking up a rule with mid-rule actions into a cascade of simple rules with ending actions is not a complete equivalence.  According to [Levine et al](http://www.amazon.com/Lex-Yacc-John-R-Levine/dp/B00007FYCY/)  there are some obscure cases where the grammar becomes ambiguous.

Comment: For terminals, the value set in Lex becomes the semantic value because of the default rule { $$ = $1; }